# Digital equivalent of a double-throw switch?

Tags: switches, dpdt

I'm designing a circuit that would switch between stereo-jack inputs. Source audio would be plugged into one end, and on the other two ends, two different audio outputs. I want to be able to switch between one of the two outputs.

Physically, I know how to do this, it is very simple using a double throw switch.

However, if I want to do this digitally, using a micro-controller board to control the switching, what type of component would I use?

I know that the digital equivalent of a SPST is an NPN-transistor. What is the digital equivalent of DT switch? Any support multiple poles?

A poor diagram of what I want to do.

[image: Switcher]

Comment: For audio I'd go for a relay.

Comment: I second that with DPDT latching relays 50mW coil http://pewa.panasonic.com/assets/pcsd/catalog/tx-s-catalog.pdf

Comment: Note that you probably don't want to switch the sleeve, lest you introduce a [Pin 1 problem](http://pin1problem.com/) into your circuit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is an [analog switch](http://www.maximintegrated.com/products/switches/5v/). The control lines are selected via digital IO but the signals passing through are analog.

Comment: While I would also go for an analog switch in the first instance, if for some reason they are unsuitable (e.g. biasing problems, or problems with the series resistance of a few hundred ohms they typically exhibit) then a DP3T relay might be more suitable.

Comment: @markt - There are ~2Ω series resistance analog switches. Or you could always buffer the signal after the analog switch.

Comment: @ConnorWolf All true, but a fair bit of extra electronics.  A relay & driver is very minimalist.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your insightful answers! I think I will use a double-throw relay. They seem to be pretty easy to find.